# How to enter the numbers or characters through keyboard in protractor?

Tags: input, keyboard, protractor, numbers, awtrobot

i want to enter the numeric values through keyboard using protractor.in java we are using 'robot class 'for entering the keyboard values, is there any class in protractor like 'robot'.

Comment: Can you post what research you have done or what steps you have already tried?

Comment: Hi, i am searching the code for keyboard action but everyone posting browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform(); code only .i want code for numeric values

Comment: Is there a reason why sendKeys is unsuitable for your situation?

Comment: yes, in angular page we are setting scale value through keyboard only?

Comment: `.sendKeys` mimicks keyboard entries. Why not use `.sendKeys('0123')`?

Answer (score 0):

you could try with the num pad key constants. e.g if you want to press '5', go with: `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.NUMPAD5).perform();`